# How to allow only certain users to execute a smart contract method?

Tags: ethereum, access-control, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a smart contract with admin, regular user and commenter roles. I also have two different methods , one only admin can execute and another only commenter can. I saw that open zeppelin has roles library which can be used to define roles. Is there a way I can do it without openzeppelin? Do I need to use mapping? User logs into another portal and only userid of logged in user is passed to the contract method. So, I want to map these userids to admin, commenter or regular user.
Thanks in advance for help .

Answer (score 0):

The basic of access control is that you check the sender address of the transaction.

```
 contract Foo {

   address owner;

   function superDuperPriviledge()  public {
       require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can do this")
   }

}
```

For your use case, having two different methods it does not sound using a library makes any sense and simple `require()` is enough.

Comment: Ok. is it possible to have 3 different roles and map each user's address to a role. For example: associate 0xabc address to reviewer and check it before the function is executed?

Comment: Yes, just make a new address variable for each role and then you check afgainst it.